# I only have row key inside my mapr-db JSON table

Tags: hbase, mapr, streamsets

I don't know if it is a common problem with mapr-db JSON.
I use a Streamsets destination which is a Mapr-DB JSON table to push records containing 10 columns. I precise the first column to become a row key. when I go to

```
mapr dbshell
find /tmp/my_table
```

I only see the row key in JSON and no others columns

```
{"_id":"mykey1"}
{"_id":"mykey2"}
{"_id":"mykey3"}
{"_id":"mykey4"}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest checking the directory permissions for the user who is trying to access `/tmp/my_table`.  I know `/tmp` is typically wide-open.  But in my experience, you need read permission to get the data, and MapR seems to permit all users to see the row keys, regardless of directory permissions.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes (without comment!) on this answer. It looks ok to me!

Comment: FYI, the StreamSets community has a mailing list etc -
 see https://streamsets.com/community

Answer (score 0):

The user you are running the `mapr dbshell` command as seems to not have read permissions on the table data.

Try running the command as the mapr user, eg:

```
su - mapr
mapr dbshell find /tmp/my_table
```

The mapr user is an administrative user on the cluster and is able to read the data in the table. For production scenario's you can exclude the mapr user from reading data for security reasons.